# Java Displaytags: custom column with form and action

Tags: java, displaytag

Java Tomcat application.
I am using displaytags to render tables with data.
I am passing the List from my application and JSP displaytags is just rendering it (and displaying). I need to use displaytags to have a possibility to sort tables based on different columns.

But right now i need to have the action (form) for each row - to have a possibility to remove that record from mysql database.

Is there any possibility to add one more column using a custom value (with a form with custom value derived from every record id) ?

Thanks,

Comment: Yes, there is. Put whatever you want inside the `display:column` tag body

Comment: Use `media` type to write whatever you want into your `display:column`.